# Create a bootable installer for High Sierra under macOS Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, install, catalina, software-update

**Question**
I'm trying to create a bootable installer for High Sierra 10.13.6 under Catalina. To create the installer app I invoked the `softwareupdate` command this way:

`sudo softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.13.6`

Obviously the download started. Then after reporting a progress of about 60% it failed:

```
Downloading and installing 10.13.6 installer
Install failed with error: Update not found
```

Any idea what went wrong here? Any advice is highly welcome.

**Hardware-Software-Environment**

MacBook Pro 2019 running macOS 10.15.4 Catalina. There is no encryption enabled.

**Background**
As discussed in the first two posts mentioned below you may start with the recipe from this article [How to upgrade to macOS High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969). This provides you with the[App Store link](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12). At least for me, when initiating the download from a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan, this resulted in creating only the stub installer (as described, among others, in the references below).

**References**
These two posts, although somewhat more general, are closely related to my above question:

[How do I download macOS High Sierra for offline install?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311763/how-do-i-download-macos-high-sierra-for-offline-install/387716#387716)

[macOS High Sierra media installer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299731/macos-high-sierra-media-installer/387711#387711)

Discussing use cases of the option `--fetch-full-installer` of the  `softwareupdate`command new in macOS Catalina
https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2019/10/28/downloading-macos-installers-with-updated-signing-certificates-on-macos-catalina/

Comment: You can download the installer using links given at https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos using a command line tool that lets you pause and resume the download. wget for example.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. At the first glance I recognize a lot of Security Updates. Do you think there is a full installer download available for High Sierra?

Comment: yes there are many: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra#Release_history look for combo update

Comment: @ankii, The link you provided does not offer the full installer of any version of macOS nor can one use `wget` (which is not a default manOS utility), to download the full installer of macOS as a single application bundle directly from Apple as if what's typically present in `/Applications` as when done from the App Store's download is complete.

Comment: @user3439894 it seems I had  Xcode in my mind & I applied the same thing here. App Store is the way to go then. (also : brew install wget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - this seems to work only if the executing mac does support running the target OS. A download of 10.13.6 succeeds on MacMini7,1 and in a VM but fails on a MacMini8,1. Given that, it is likely you also get hardware specific builds if these are available for a given OS.

The `installinstallmacos.py` [script](https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts) lists all available options and does show `Unsupported Board ID` or `Unsupported macOS version` in cases that are not supported but it is able to download the installers from supposably the same source as the `softwareupdate` tool.

So either run `softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer` on compatible hardware, in a VM or use `installinstallmacos.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with your considerations. To preserve them for the annals of computer science I'll restate them as **Bussmann's conjeture** : The `softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer` command is likely to create hardware specific builds if these are available for a given OS.

Comment: I also agree with your reference to Greg Neagle's
`installinstallmacos.py` script. For details see my post of 2020-04-17 in this thread
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311763/how-do-i-download-macos-high-sierra-for-offline-install/387716#comment533144_387716 .