# Creating a bootable macOS installer error

Tags: macos, mac

I'm following [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) guide by Apple, but it's giving me an error. When I execute

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/disco
```

It gives me this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/IAESD
  Referenced from: /Applications/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/../Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/IAESD: mmap() error 1 at address=0x103C4F000, size=0x00006000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /Applications/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/../Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/IAESD
    /Applications/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/../Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/IAESD: mmap() error 1 at address=0x103C65000, size=0x00006000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /Applications/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/../Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/IAESD
ADMINs-MBP-2:~ ADMIN$
```

I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 on a Macbook Pro 2015.

The USB device is a 1TB External Hard Drive, Mac OS Extended formatted.

Comment: You need to re-download the installer.  Also, don't you have a 16GB USB flash anywhere?  a 1TB USB drive is awfully huge and will take forever to partition, format and image.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of the installers, they have a special version of `createinstallmedia` in the same folder called `createinstallmedia_yosemite` that takes the same arguments as the other. I don't have Yosemite to test this, but I'd place my money on that one being the one to use.

Example location of this executable in installer:
`"Install macOS Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia_yosemite"`

Answer (score 0):

Installer files might be not available in the installer

Proceed with https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307118

UPD: so even after processing steps you still receive such error. The problem is because of macos yosemite. When using the same app on 10.14 it works. Don't known, maybe some earlier versions would also work.